# How to show Puerto Rico in "albersUsa" projection in Vega-Lite or Vega?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, united-states, d3, albers

I have a shapefile that has all the US counties along with Puerto Rico and I want to visualize them in "albersUsa" projection using Vega or Vega-Lite.

Problem is that in other projections, Puerto Rico is visible but in "albersUsa" projeciton it vanishes.

The closest I got to is [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/u-s-map-with-puerto-rico) by Mike Bostock.

You can download the `counties-10m.json` file over there.

Is there a way to render it completely(including Puerto Rico) as an "albersUsa" projection?

My biggest concern is that the "albersUsa" projection itself won't allow Puerto Rico to be displayed.

Any leads on how do I go about using a composite projection in Vega. Since there is an example in d3 and Vega is built on top of d3, I suppose there should be a way.

**EDIT**

It looks like the [file here](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/hispanic-or-latino-origin-by-u-s-county) has a projected version of Puerto Rico in albersUsa projection.

However, when I plot it in Vega-Lite using "albersUsa" projection, I get the following -
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Vega does not support the AlbersUSA projection with Puerto Rico in it because the D3 implementation doesn't either. You can add a custom projection to Vega, though. See https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/extensibility/#projections for documentation on how to add a custom projection.

Comment: Is there a way to do it via the JSON specifications? I am a little comfortable with Vega-Lite and Altair but not with Vega. So it may take a very long time for me to actually grasp how to make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately not since you need to provide the implementation of the projection.

Comment: That makes sense. So for the implementation we would need a javascript file right? Something like [this](https://github.com/datavis-tech/pleth/blob/4e916c05d7c3375cfdaa00172670c287a15a1205/packages/examples/src/pleth/geoAlbersUsaTerritories.js) or [this](https://github.com/stamen/dirty-reprojectors/blob/master/projections/albers-usa-territories.js) ? The next question is, where do I keep the js files so that it is used instead of the default files that does not have the implementation of the projection? How will a Vega spec make use of the new implementation in these files?